# Maximum velocity on Unbanked roads and why should friction be more than centripetal force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, centripetal-force, free-body-diagram

Why is maximum velocity on unbanked circular road given by $\sqrt{urg}$ where $u$ is coefficient of friction, $r$ is radius of circular track and $g$ is acceleration due to gravity?
Why should frictional force be more than centripetal force? What will happen if centripetal force is more than friction?
I was absent when this topic was taught in the class so there might be some mistakes in the question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows insufficient prior research

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is not enough friction to keep the vehicle in its circular path, it will skid. The force needed for the circular path is the centripetal force: friction (the force keeping the car on the road) must be greater that that. Now the no-slip condition (centripetal force < friction) implies = $\frac{mv^2}{r} < mg\mu$ . Your equation follows by simple manipulation.

Comment: If centripetal force is more than frictional force it will skid off while if  frictional force is greater than centripetal force the car will stay on road. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You are correct and this is what I said? I admit I wrote it in a confusing manner. In one line I said "skid when x", in the next I wrote "not x implies y"...